# How to convert pdf to chm files?

Tags: software-recommendation, format-conversion

I'm looking for some good tools in the Ubuntu platform which does convert the PDF to CHM files. I googled a lot. But I almost finding the tools for other way around (i.e CHM to PDF).

Comment: I cannot fully answer your question, because I don't work with compiled html help, but I guess, the first step is to go from the vector graphics format PDF to the markup language HTML. For this there exists a command line tool called pdftohtml which you can find in the poppler-utils package. Since converting from a graphics format to a formatted text format is not trivial, results may vary.

Answer (score 2):

You can Download [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/%E2%80%8E) .***Calibre*** is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books.

calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to every output format.

Input Formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX, EPUB, FB2, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ

Output Formats: AZW3, EPUB, FB2, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, HTMLZ, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ

***It does perform .pdf to .chm conversion***

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317314/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-the-pdf-files-to-chm?answertab=votes#tab-top)