# Is there a tool to convert the pdf files to chm?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for any package or tool to convert **pdf** files to 
**chm**. Is there such a tool?

I am running Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Download [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) .Calibre is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books.

calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to every output format.

Input Formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX, EPUB, FB2, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ

Output Formats: AZW3, EPUB, FB2, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, HTMLZ, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ

***It does perform .pdf to .chm conversion***
The calibre manuals for conversion can be accessed here:

- http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#conversion
- [manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html#ebook-convert](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html#ebook-convert)

You Can download it [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)

After installation of Calibre,you can start it by typing the command `calibre&` in terminal
there are two ways to use it:

1. use the gui of the calibre .This is pretty straight forward.
2. By using the command ebook-convert in terminal as follows

   `ebook-convert filetobeconverted.pdf outputfile.chm -h`

   if the file name has space then put it in parenthesis .For example 
   (my book is this .pdf )

Comment: humm.. thanks for your heads up. But I like .chm files for reading. Need to .pdf to .chm tool if any.

Comment: put the needed link in your answer not in comment.. :) I never used this before,so what command should I run to make it happens from *pdf to chm* conversions.

Comment: @Stormvirux: If this was ever possible with an earlier version of Calibre, it obviously now isn't!  I've just installed version 4.99.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.1.  The odd thing here is that even in your notes above, you clearly show that `CHM` is not in the list of `Output Formats`.  Are you sure this ever worked?  If you can prove this works, I'll remove my downvote.