# Is there any tool for converting from .pdf to .chm?

Tags: file-format, convert

I googled this title and all I encountered was chm -> pdf searches. Isn't it possible from pdf to chm ? Or if it is possible which tools do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be what you're looking for, but the only way I know how to do it, is using [PDF2CHM](http://dawningsoft.com/pdf-to-chm.html).

The only problem it only available for windows.  So your option is to run it under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this question, seems to be asking pretty much the same thing.

[Is there a tool to convert the pdf files to chm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317314/package-or-tool-to-convert-the-pdf-files-to-chm-in-ubuntu?rq=1)

The leading answer suggests using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try chm2pdf, to get it:

`sudo apt-get install chm2pdf`

Comment: The OP wants to go from pdf to chm.